# Logitech DiNovo Edge USB Bluetooth keyboard quit working after 12.04lts to 14.04lts upgrade

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade, usb, bluetooth

I noticed this after upgrading my desktop (commodity PC parts) from 12.04lts to 14.04 lts. Upgrade done with updater after being notified yesterday that there was a new release available. I've been poking at it for some hours on several computers. Two have the problem and one seems fine. Starting with this desktop the logs show a difference between versions on the same machine in the syslog bluetooth startup.

The bluetooth device is a Logitech Edge keyboard with a USB Bluetooth 2.0 adapter.

12.04lts (working):

```
Aug 12 21:27:26 ceora bluetoothd[1058]: Bluetooth daemon 4.98
Aug 12 21:27:26 ceora bluetoothd[1058]: Starting SDP server
Aug 12 21:27:26 ceora bluetoothd[1058]: Failed to init alert plugin
Aug 12 21:27:26 ceora bluetoothd[1058]: Failed to init time plugin
Aug 12 21:27:26 ceora bluetoothd[1058]: Failed to init proximity plugin
Aug 12 21:27:26 ceora bluetoothd[1058]: Failed to init gatt_example
plugin
Aug 12 21:27:26 ceora bluetoothd[1058]: Listening for HCI events on hci0
Aug 12 21:27:26 ceora bluetoothd[1058]: HCI dev 0 up
Aug 12 21:27:27 ceora bluetoothd[1058]: Adapter /org/bluez/1058/hci0 has
been enabled
Aug 12 21:27:53 ceora bluetoothd[1058]: Endpoint registered:
sender=:1.39 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Aug 12 21:27:53 ceora bluetoothd[1058]: Endpoint registered:
sender=:1.39 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Aug 12 21:27:53 ceora bluetoothd[1058]: Endpoint registered:
sender=:1.39 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Aug 12 21:28:19 ceora bluetoothd[1058]: Endpoint registered:
sender=:1.53 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Aug 12 21:28:19 ceora bluetoothd[1058]: Endpoint registered:
sender=:1.53 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Aug 12 21:28:19 ceora bluetoothd[1058]: Endpoint registered:
sender=:1.53 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Aug 12 21:28:34 ceora bluetoothd[1058]: Endpoint unregistered:
sender=:1.39 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Aug 12 21:28:34 ceora bluetoothd[1058]: Endpoint unregistered:
sender=:1.39 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Aug 12 21:28:34 ceora bluetoothd[1058]: Endpoint unregistered:
sender=:1.39 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
```

14.04lts (broken):

```
Aug 14 12:30:18 ceora bluetoothd[5360]: Bluetooth daemon 4.101
Aug 14 12:30:18 ceora bluetoothd[5360]: Starting SDP server
Aug 14 12:30:18 ceora bluetoothd[5360]: DIS cannot start: GATT is disabled
Aug 14 12:30:18 ceora bluetoothd[5360]: Failed to init deviceinfo plugin
Aug 14 12:30:18 ceora bluetoothd[5360]: Failed to init proximity plugin
Aug 14 12:30:18 ceora bluetoothd[5360]: Failed to init time plugin
Aug 14 12:30:18 ceora bluetoothd[5360]: Failed to init alert plugin
Aug 14 12:30:18 ceora bluetoothd[5360]: Failed to init thermometer plugin
Aug 14 12:30:18 ceora bluetoothd[5360]: Failed to init gatt_example plugin
Aug 14 12:30:18 ceora bluetoothd[5360]: Bluetooth Management interface initialized
```

For the computer that works with 14.04 (a Dell mini 910):

```
Aug 14 12:32:12 dellmini bluetoothd[7378]: Bluetooth daemon 4.101
Aug 14 12:32:12 dellmini bluetoothd[7378]: Starting SDP server
Aug 14 12:32:12 dellmini bluetoothd[7378]: DIS cannot start: GATT is disabled
Aug 14 12:32:12 dellmini bluetoothd[7378]: Failed to init deviceinfo plugin
Aug 14 12:32:12 dellmini bluetoothd[7378]: Failed to init proximity plugin
Aug 14 12:32:12 dellmini bluetoothd[7378]: Failed to init time plugin
Aug 14 12:32:12 dellmini bluetoothd[7378]: Failed to init alert plugin
Aug 14 12:32:12 dellmini bluetoothd[7378]: Failed to init thermometer plugin
Aug 14 12:32:12 dellmini bluetoothd[7378]: Failed to init gatt_example plugin
Aug 14 12:32:12 dellmini bluetoothd[7378]: Bluetooth Management interface initialized
Aug 14 12:32:12 dellmini bluetoothd[7378]: Adapter /org/bluez/7378/hci0 has been enabled
Aug 14 12:32:12 dellmini bluetoothd[7378]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.67 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Aug 14 12:32:12 dellmini bluetoothd[7378]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.67 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Aug 14 12:32:12 dellmini bluetoothd[7378]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.67 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Aug 14 12:32:12 dellmini bluetoothd[7378]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.67 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Aug 14 12:32:12 dellmini bluetoothd[7378]: hci0: Load Long Term Keys (0x0013) failed: Not Supported (0x0c)
```

Note the line referring to Adapter `/org/bluez/1058/hci0` is present in the working configurations and missing in the broken. I also have an Acer Aspire One running 14.04 that has the same symptoms/logs as my broken desktop and the bluetooth is broken there, too. I did have the bluetooth keyboard working on the Acer with either 13.04 or 13.10, but I can't remember which.

From the user interface the breakage shows itself in the **System Settings -> Bluetooth** as everything greyed out with **No Bluetooth adapters found** in the adapter list. The check box to Show Bluetooth status in the menu bar will check, but nothing shows.

Comment: I use the DiNovo Edge with the stock dongle and have no problems. Up until now.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my question seems to be that I need to hold the red button on the dongle when inserting it. The behavior is different than before, but seems reasonable. I never used the red button before.

I tested this through a warm reboot and cold shutdown. The connection survived both. I only needed to re-pair if I pulled the dongle out and reinserted it. To review, the steps to make it work are:

1. Insert the dongle while holding down the red button on it.
2. Open the System Settings -> Bluetooth utility. Now the option to turn on bluetooth is not greyed out and bluetooth turns on.
3. Add the device and pair it and it works!